How to build enumerated Types with "classes"?
I have an enumerated type like Type1=(left,right,up,down)
I usually have to build a function to convert this to a string for output.
case Type of
left: result:='left'
right: result:='right'
.
.
.
end

Is there any way I can do something like Type.toString while still having a simple assignment with Type:=left?

What does this have to do with "classes"?

As the term is quoted, it somehow matches the official documentation of advanced records: 'In addition to the traditional record types, the Delphi language allows more complex and "class-like" record types.'

This can be done with a record helper, which despite its name works even for enumerations.
type 
  Type1 = (left, right, up, down);
  Type1Helper = record helper for Type1
    function ToString: string;
  end; 


 function Type1Helper.ToString: string;
 begin
   case Self of
     left: result := 'left';
     right: result := 'right';
     up: result := 'up'; 
     down: result := 'down';
   end;
 end;


Alternatively, you can replace the case with RTTI: Result := GetEnumName(TypeInfo(Type1), Ord(Self));

@RemyLebeau: Or, in newer versions of Delphi, TRttiEnumerationType.GetName(Self)
